# Insert a node in between text

Tags: javascript, dom

I am familiar with inserting text nodes after or before a given reference node. But, I would like to know how to insert a tag between text in a given node. For example,

```
Before insertion: <p>Lorem dolor</p>
After insertion: <p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor</p>
```

The span node must be inserted after N characters (I don't need user's cursor selection position) within another another node. Is that possible?

Answer (score 20):

The proper way (using DOM-Core interfaces including [the `splitText()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText)) would be:

```
var p = document.getElementById('myParagraph');
var text = p.childNodes[0];
var at = 5;

// create new span node with content
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('ipsum'));

// Split the text node into two and add new span
p.insertBefore(span, text.splitText(at));
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to get the text into a variable then remove it from the DOM.
Split it, then insert the first part, then your span node then the second part.

```
var p = document.getElementById('myParagraph');
var text = p.childNodes[0];

// Split the text
var len = 5
var text1 = text.nodeValue.substr(0, len);
var text2 = text.nodeValue.substr(len);

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' dolor'));

// Remove the existing text
p.removeChild(p.childNodes[0]);

// Put the new text in
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text1));
p.appendChild(span);
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text2));
```

Comment: The answer using `splitText` is simpler and requires fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You could check a nodes `innerHTML` property and modify that. Alternatively you might look at `childNodes` collection and work with elements there (deleting the old text node and inserting new nodes in its place).